# Are there any public web services that expose their logs?

Tags: web-services

I'm doing some testing, and need a publicly, no auth available server on the internet that exposes its logs. I could go spin up a webserver in heroku or something like that, but feel there must be something out there that lets me do this with zero work already ;-)

So for example, if I make a request against this web service, I can later look in this services logs in some way, and see a request was made to my url or not.

In theory this would let me do something like so:

http://someWebService/any/request?bp=5

and then look at the access logs later on to see if my request was made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that [mockbin](http://mockbin.com) can be used for this purpose!

It's a free service by Mashape that allows anyone to setup a mock reset API, *and* view the access logs for their requests via another REST call!